# calculating a limit of sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Can some one help to show that for $a>0$
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a^\frac{1}{n}}{n+1}+\frac{a^\frac{2}{n}}{n+\frac{1}{2}}+...+\frac{a^\frac{n}{n}}{n+\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{a-1}{\log a}$$

My tries : I was not able to use riemann sum for calculating. 
For the special case $a=1$ the RHS has limit $1$ and for the LHS for $a=1$ we can write

$$\frac{n}{n+1} \le \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}+...+\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{n}} \le \frac{n}{n+\frac{1}{n}} $$ so the limit of LHS is $1$ . For arbitrary $a$ I have failed to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let

$$S(n) = \frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n + 1} + \frac{a^{\frac{2}{n}}}{n + \frac{1}{2}} + \cdots + \frac{a^{\frac{n}{n}}}{n + \frac{1}{n}}.$$

Then

$$\frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n + 1} + \frac{a^{\frac{2}{n}}}{n + 1} +  \cdots + \frac{a^{\frac{n}{n}}}{n + 1} < S(n) < \frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n} + \frac{a^{\frac{2}{n}}}{n} +\cdots + \frac{a^{\frac{n}{n}}}{n}$$

that is,

$$\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot \frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}} + a^{\frac{2}{n}} + \cdots + a^{\frac{n}{n}}}{n} < S(n) < \frac{a^{\frac{1}{n}} + a^{\frac{2}{n}}+\cdots + a^{\frac{n}{n}}}{n}. \tag{*}$$

The left- and right-most sides of $(*)$ converge to

$$\int_0^1 a^x\, dx = \frac{a^x}{\log a}\bigg|_{x = 0}^1 = \frac{a - 1}{\log a}.$$

Hence, by the squeeze theorem,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} S(n) = \frac{a - 1}{\log a}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The Riemanian sum appears from
$$\frac{a^{k/n}}{n+\frac1k}=\frac{a^{k/n}}n\frac{1}{1+\frac1{nk}}.$$

Developing the last fraction $1-\frac1{nk}+\frac1{n^2k^2}\cdots$, the high order terms vanish as $\frac1n$.